# How can I enable node.js application logs on from cpanel?

Tags: node.js, cpanel, error-logging

I have a node.js application that sends email using nodemailer. It is working fine from localhost but when I try it from server I can't receive any mail.

Since, other activities of application are working fine means I assumed nodemailer is installed properly on server. I tried on both ways using host as my server and using gmail as on of the services. Here, is what I tried last time. This also works fine on local host. But, I don't get any response when I put this on server.

I have nodemailer's configuration as:

```
const output = `
    <h3>Limit Details</h3>
    <p>Admin has added ${limit} quota(s) to ${username}.</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 25,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: '<gmail>', 
        pass: '<password>' 
    }
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
      from: '"Sender" <sender gmail>', // sender address
      to: '<receiver gmail>', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Quota added information.', // Subject line
      html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  });
```

For testing, I have consoled messageId and Preview Url So, from where I can view this console message in cpanel? How can I view such consoled stuffs from my application in cpanel??

Comment: cPanel's nodeJS Application Manager doesn't really feel like it does much, so I'm using PM2 again after trying out cPanel's "solution".
I created a feature request with cPanel if you want to upvote it, maybe they'll improve it someday?
https://features.cpanel.net/topic/node-js-logs-monitoring-and-watching

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to access node's logs on a cpanel server as far as I know.
What I usually do is I set up [log4js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js) to write logs to a file:

```
const log4js = require('log4js');

log4js.configure({
  appenders: { everything: { type: 'file', filename: 'logs.log' } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['everything'], level: 'ALL' } }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger();
```

Then you can make logs with:

```
logger.debug('log message');
```

You can also serve the log file with the server:

```
app.get('/log', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/logs.log'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

cPanel's Application manager isn't very fleshed-out. I've been trying it out and comparing it to what I'm used to (PM2) and will be switching back to PM2. 
I did put up a feature request to cPanel if anyone's interested in supporting.

Otherwise, the answer is to write out using a custom logger such as @zenott suggests. However, I prefer to overwrite console.log though so it's easy to switch back to regular console logging if needed.

My solution:

```
const moment = require('moment')
const fs = require('fs')
let logStream = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt')
let console = {}
console.log = (obj) => {
  var s = ''
  if (typeof obj === 'string')
    s = obj
  else
    s = JSON.stringify(obj)

  var dS = '[' + moment().format(momentFormat) + '] '
  s = `[${dS}] ${s}'\n'`
  logStream.write(s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to access your NodeJS app logs on a cPanel server.
Instead of using:

```
console.log()
```

Use:

```
console.error()
```

This will populate the `stderr.log` file located in your NodeJS app's root folder on your cPanel without holding back.
It will even output Circular and JSON formats without any need to `stringify()`.

### UPDATE:

The above will only work when cPanel is running on CloudLinux (`Setup NodeJS App` is available).

For other Distros (with only `Application Manager` available), just paste the below at the Main `App.js` file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/debug.log', {flags: 'w'});
const log_stdout = process.stdout;

console.log = (d, e, f, g) => {
  log_file.write(util.format('LOG: ', d?d:'', e?e:'', f?f:'', g?g:'') + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format('LOG: ', d?d:'', e?e:'', f?f:'', g?g:'') + '\n');
}

console.error = (d, e, f, g) => {
  log_file.write(util.format('ERROR: ', d?d:'', e?e:'', f?f:'', g?g:'') + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format('ERROR: ', d?d:'', e?e:'', f?f:'', g?g:'') + '\n');
}
```

Then use `console.log()` as usual across all cascading modules.
This will create and populate a `debug.log` file located in your NodeJS app's root folder.
You may also use `console.trace()` to get the line number for the error.
Use the command  `tail -f debug.log` in terminal for live logging.