# Is there a way to get the console output in CPANEL for a node process?

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I am trying to migrate a node application from heroku to cpanel and not capturing anything in my log file. Here is a code example. Would this be because of serving the public folder, potentially?

````
let app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
const log4js = require('log4js');

log4js.configure({
  appenders: { everything: { type: 'file', filename: 'logs.log' } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['everything'], level: 'ALL' } }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger();

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    logger.debug("DOUBLE CHECKING CONSOLE");
    res.send("APP IS LISTENING!");
});```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable node.js application logs on from cpanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200795/how-can-i-enable-node-js-application-logs-on-from-cpanel)

Comment: That's what I am trying, but I am not seeing the console logs being hit from the routes hit.